# subdomain grouping misses slash in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to write a simple REST API backend that resides on
`http://api.stan.test/`.
Got `laravel/framework:v7.21.0` and `PHP:7.2.30`.

Can't get the route matched.

#### The problem:

#### when I am accessing the `http://api.stan.test/api/t.json` URL

- With `api.stan.test` string as domain group, my route in `\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::match` is compared to `api.stan.testapi/user` alias and route is not found obviously.
- With `api.stan.test/` string as domain group, my route in `\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::match` is compared against `api.stan.test/api/user` alias, match is found but it fails domain validation in `\Illuminate\Routing\Route::matches`.

`preg_match($hostRegex, $request->getHost())` fails because

`preg_match("{^api\.stan\.test/$}sDiu", "api.stan.test")` are the values.

This is my RouteServiceProvider

```php
# \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::mapApiRoutes
Route::domain('api.stan.test')
            ->prefix('/api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

and here is included routes file

```
# routes/api.php
Route::get('t.json','TController@api');
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel**, route parameters matching uses **Symfony**'s **Route compiler**. Actually route compiler was finding dot (`.`) as a **segment separator**. This is the reason why in your case it cannot find the route.
You can do something like this :

```
Route::get('t_json','TController@api');
```

Comment: Thanks, will look into that compilation, but for now I moved the prefix() call from \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::mapApiRoutes to routes/api.php and it began to work.